# How to read a JSON file into a Map, using Scala

Tags: scala, gatling, jsonpath

How can I read a JSON file into a Map, using Scala.  I've been trying to accomplish this but the JSON I am reading is nested JSon and I have not found a way to easily extract the JSON into keys because of that.  Scala seems to be wanting to also convert the nested JSON String into an object. Instead, I want the nested JSON as a String "value". I am hoping someone can clarify or give me a hint on how I might do this.

My JSON source might look something like this:

```
{
  "authKey": "34534645645653455454363",
  "member": {
    "memberId": "whatever",
    "firstName": "Jon",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "address": {
      "line1": "Whatever Rd",
      "city": "White Salmon",
      "state": "WA",
      "zip": "98672"
    },
    "anotherProp": "wahtever",
  }
}
```

I want to extract this JSON into a Map of 2 keys without drilling into the nested JSON.   Is this possible?   Once I have the Map, my intention is to add the key-values to my POST request headers, like so:

```
val sentHeaders = Map("Content-Type" -> "application/javascript", 
   "Accept" -> "text/html", "authKey" -> extractedValue,
   "member" -> theMemberInfoAsStringJson)
http("Custom headers")
.post("myUrl")
.headers(sentHeaders)
```

Comment: Does it mean you are only interested in first-level keys?

Comment: Yes, first level keys only.  So, i would want 1st level values as String, not as json/object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question is tagged 'gatling', behind the curtains this lib depends on Jackson/fasterxml for JSON processing, so we can make use of it.

There is no way to retrieve a nested structured part of JSON as String directly, but with very few additional code the result can still be achieved.

So, having the input JSON:

```
val json = """{
             |  "authKey": "34534645645653455454363",
             |  "member": {
             |    "memberId": "whatever",
             |    "firstName": "Jon",
             |    "lastName": "Doe",
             |    "address": {
             |      "line1": "Whatever Rd",
             |      "city": "White Salmon",
             |      "state": "WA",
             |      "zip": "98672"
             |    },
             |    "anotherProp": "wahtever"
             |  }
             |}""".stripMargin
```

A Jackson's `ObjectMapper` can be created and configured for use in Scala:

```
// import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule

val mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
```

To parse the input json easily, a dedicated case class is useful:

```
case class SrcJson(authKey: String, member: Any) {
  val memberAsString = mapper.writeValueAsString(member)
}
```

We also include `val memberAsString` in it, which will contain our target JSON string, obtained through a reverse conversion from initially parsed `member` which actually is a `Map`.

Now, to parse the input json:

```
val parsed = mapper.readValue(json, classOf[SrcJson])
```

The references `parsed.authKey` and `parsed.memberAsString` will contain the researched values.

Comment: I am needing to do this in context of Gatling project.  In the gatling libs folder, there is not a jar for jackson-module-scala  dependency.  I assume that is how  you would get com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala package?

Comment: You need to add dependency in a build.sbt.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Also, it seems gatling has a built-in for reading Json called "Feeder".  I need to investigate.

Answer (score -1):

have a look at the scala play library - it has support for handling JSON. From what you describe, it should be pretty straightforward to read in the JSON and get the string value from any desired node.

[Scala Play - JSON](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson#JSON-basics)

Comment: I wouldn't want to use a Play library.  If I wanted to import a library, i would install json.simple or Groovy-all to get json-slurper.